# Split bracket data into row in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data in table. The questionid 201 belongs to option_3 and option_4 but when the following query is used it returns null for second output. It Should be display 201 as well.

```
create table test 
(id integer,
questionid character varying (255),
questionanswer character varying (255));

INSERT INTO test (id,questionid,questionanswer) VALUES
     (1,'[101,102,103]','[["option_11"],["KILA ALIPOKUWA ANAUMWA YEYE ALIJUWA NI AROSTO HALI YA KUKOSA KUVUTA MADAWA.."],["option_14"]]'),
     (2,'[201]','[["option_3","option_4"]]');

--my query

SELECT *, 
replace(unnest(string_to_array(translate(questionid, '],[ ', '","'), ',' ))::text,'"','') as questionid,
replace(unnest(string_to_array(translate(questionanswer, '],[ ', '","'), ',' ))::text,'"','') as questionanswer
from test;
```

[image]

Comment: This is a horrible way to store that information do you have any chance to fix this before continuing?

Comment: yes it is, this data is extracted from mongodb collection via etl.

Comment: Seems it would be easier to change the ETL. Have `questionid` be `integer`. Then do `INSERT INTO test (id,questionid,questionanswer) VALUES (1, 201, "option_3"), (2, 201, "option_4");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a series of `cross join`s:

```
select t.id, t1.val, v1#>>'{}' from test t 
cross join lateral (select row_number() over (order by v.value#>>'{}') r, v.value#>>'{}' val 
   from json_array_elements(t.questionid::json) v) t1
join lateral (select row_number() over (order by 1) r, v.value val 
   from json_array_elements(t.questionanswer::json) v) t2 on t1.r = t2.r
cross join lateral json_array_elements(t2.val) v1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zL5ewdx-).

Comment: Hi Ajax1234, I have added the new question, could you see.